# Thumbnail image generation taking too long time

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am generating thumbnail from Azure media services.

Some times it takes 2 minutes for generating thumbnail of time frame 50 seconds and some times it takes 10 minutes for the same 50 second of time frame to create thumbnail while there is no other job in queue.

please suggest any solution for this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Reserved Units on your account?
By default, if you have no Media Processing units enabled, it will just submit your job to the general shared pool where there is no SLA and you may stay queued until a resource is available (depends on how busy the region is).

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-scale-media-processing-overview